# MySQL SELECT excluding several ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is populated by a driver recording events occurring on hardware, when a client app is executing a special procedure (say manteinance), the events saved during this operation are due to the user and not by the I/O (sensors and stuff), to deal with this, since I need to save all posible events (wether it occurred by normal operation or by user manipulation).
I need to be able to filter those "maintenance mode" data and get the automatically generated info, in order to do this I am inserting "START" and "END" rows in the table populated by the hardware, son I can know when the non functional data begins and where it ends, something like this:

```
id | fieldlist... 
---+--------------------
 1 | event1 
 2 | event2 
 3 | event3 
 4 | manteinance start (inserted by me)
 5 | event_by_technician1 
 6 | event_by_technician2
 7 | event_by_technician3
 8 | manteinance finish (inserted by me)
 9 | event4 
 10| event5 
 11| manteinance start (inserted by me)
 12| event_by_technicianx 
 13| event_by_techniciany
 14| manteinance finish (inserted by me)
 15| eventA 
 16| manteinance start (inserted by me)
 17| event_by_technician 
 18| manteinance finish (inserted by me)
 19| many many more records and start/finish pairs...
```

I need to filter all those event_by_technician* and get only the event* rows, is there a way to query for the info clean and easy, for a variable and non uniform set of ranges?

Thanks

EDIT: I think I am not being clear, there's two applications running on server, my php based web application, and an external driver. Both scripts/applications access the same database, the driver inserts data from sensors and other hardware status, and the web app reads that and shows some pretty nice graphics with it (it inserts 'signaling' rows on user requests i.e. a button clicked). It's just not possible to determine by comparisson if an event is from manteinance or from normal operation because they are just the same, what differentiate them is if the technician clicked a button on the web page to start, and another when finished.
What I need is asking Mysql: "Hey, just give me the rows that are not between a row with field1=1 (start) and another with field1=2 (end). Considering there're many start/end pairs along the result.

I think I'm taking the way of refactoring the table with php putting an extra column to the data between the start/end rows looping around the resultset. And then making my querys.

Comment: Don't do that, it will make filtering much harder.  Add a column, default to false, called `maintenance_event` and set it true on all maintenance events.  Then filtering is trivial.

Comment: So, what is your expected output?

Comment: The thing is that I don't insert that data, a separate driver running inserts the data without knowing when an event is due to mainteinance or an operational one, I (php) just know when the user starts the app before putting his/her hands on the hardware and when finishes (by ending operation on the app), that's why I'm trying that way. My other thoughs are for walking back on the result with php and re-format the data over and over (setting a field like you say for example), but that seems to be a little messy.

Comment: @MostyMostacho the expected output would be like:  
 1 | event1 
 2 | event2 
 3 | event3 
 9 | event4 
 10| event5 
 15| eventA 
 19| many many more records WITHOUT start/finish pairs or between them...

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE and '?' to replace one character. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  fieldlist LIKE 'event?'
```

Comment: This will also return `eventA` and the OP doesn't seem to be expecting that

Comment: the use of event1, event2, eventA, eventZ, event99999 is arbitrary to show that is an event caused by normal operation, and the event_by_technitian caused by manipulation, but both are just equal in structure and form, you just couldn't tell if a record was cause by one or another, only with the timestamps of start and end. They are not litterally strings, so the LIKE doesn't work for the purposse. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Using User Defined Functions should be the most efficient way. You can go for this:

```
SELECT id, event FROM (
    SELECT id, event,
      @manteinance := (@manteinance_started OR @manteinance) AND event != 'manteinance finish' m,
      @manteinance_started := event = 'manteinance start' ms
    FROM t, (SELECT @manteinance := FALSE, @manteinance_started := FALSE) init
    HAVING m = 0
    ORDER BY id
) s
WHERE event NOT IN ('manteinance start', 'manteinance finish')
```

**Output:**

```
| ID |                                            EVENT |
|----|--------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |                                           event1 |
|  2 |                                           event2 |
|  3 |                                           event3 |
|  9 |                                           event4 |
| 10 |                                           event5 |
| 15 |                                           eventA |
| 19 | many many more records and start/finish pairs... |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a37c/1).